# styled components not work in vite react js

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I've installed using this commands `npm install --save styled-components` and I create file

**StyledHero.jsx**

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Button = styled.button`
  color: red;
  background: green;
`;
export default SimpleButton;
```

and I used this button in my project ,it's not work and I got this error.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=6c13fc1e net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

> Can someone helpe me to solve this ?

Comment: Your `Button` and export `SimpleButton` are not the same

Comment: I solved this and I got the same error